# How to make Highlight from Click-Drag on the Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, highlight

I want to make a feature that when the user click and drag the cursor on the Panel, it will show a temporary highlighted rectangle. And when the user releases his drag, the rectangle will disappear immediately.

This feature would be similar like when you click and drag on your Desktop:
[image]

I have known about [MouseMove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove(v=vs.110).aspx), but it still makes me somehow confuse. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Edited:
Ok, I have found the way with the [MouseMove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove(v=vs.110).aspx) now, and here is my code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle ee = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, ee);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            width = e.X - x;
            height = e.Y - y;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            width = 0;
            height = 0;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
}
```

But still, I have a problem when I tried to click and drag from right to the left or from bottom to the top, which will result in negative values for the rectangle. Is there any idea for this matter? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Use the panel's Paint event to draw the rectangle.  Get it to run by calling its Invalidate() method when the mouse is moved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight the Rectangular Area while Dragging it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091356/highlight-the-rectangular-area-while-dragging-it)

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, in my edited post I have found it like that way, but it still doesn't show the rectangle when I tried to click and drag from right to the left or from bottom to the top, which will result in negative values for the rectangle.

Comment: @NullException I thought that's a different case. But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms every Control provides the Event [DragEnter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter(v=vs.110).aspx), [DragOver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragover(v=vs.110).aspx) and  [DragLeave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragleave(v=vs.110).aspx) which is fired if the cursor enters, hovers or leaves the bounds of the control during drag and drop.

The MSDN description of this event shows you an example implementation.
Instead of an effect to the item you can also change the background or start to flash smth or whatever you want.

Comment: Sorry, but what I meant was not about the drag and drop feature, but it's more like simply make a rectangle when you click+hold on the panel, and delete the rectangle when you release your click.